# Threaded program wont run

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I cant seem to get my fib_worker class to run

```
import multiprocessing


 class fib_Worker(object):
     def worker(self, num):
         """thread worker function"""
        print 'Worker:', num
        return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Self.fib_Worker.worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Im getting this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method worker() must be called with fib_Worker instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Ive tried calling it different ways and not sure whats wrong thanks

edit added to mhawkes suggestions

Comment: What is `Self`? You need to instantiate `fib_Worker` somewhere, so that the thread can call its `worker` method.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `f = fib_Worker()` and then pass `f.worker` as the thread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `Self.fib_Worker`? You need to instantiate the class first:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fib_Worker().worker, args=(i,))
```

`fib_Worker()` creates an instance of class `fib_Worker`. Once you have that you can call its methods.

Also you need to add a `self` parameter to the `worker()` method:

```
    def worker(self, num):
        """thread worker function"""
        print 'Worker:', num
        return
```

Another option, since it holds no state, you can also create a single instance of the class and pass its method:

```
worker = fib_Worker().worker

for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Comment: @KyleSponable: have you tried instantiating the `fib_Worker` class as shown?